# how to add html & javascript after PHP exit

Tags: php, javascript, html, json, parsing

Please Help, nothing i add after the ?> works, i tried to put the code in a echo, but its not working would someone please put together a JSFiddle for me or point me in the right direction, i am fairly new with PHP, Thanks for the help

```
<?php
    $filepath = 'http://www.godsgypsychristianchurch.net/music.json';
    $content = file_get_contents($filepath);
    $json = json_decode($content, true);


foreach ($json['rows'] as $row)
    {
            if ($_GET['album'] == $row[doc]['album'])
            {
                        echo "<title>{$row[doc]['album']}</title>";
                        echo "<table align=\"center\" border=\"0\"><tr><td valign=\"top\" width=\"330\">";
                        echo "<img src=\"{$row['doc']['artwork']}\" alt=\"my image \" width=\"250\" /><br /><br />";
                        echo "<div class=\"albuminfo\" id=\"albuminfo\">";
                    print ' <a href=http://ggcc.tv/archivealbum.php?download=' . urlencode($row[doc]['album']) . ' id=DownloadAlbum><img src="http://ggcc.tv/musiclibrary/wp-content/plugins/zina/zina/themes/zinaEmbed/icons/download.gif" width="35">Download entire album.</a><p>';
                        echo "<font color=\"#fff\">Album: {$row[doc]['album']}</font><br />";
                        echo "<font color=\"#fff\">Church: {$row[doc]['church']}</font><br />";
                        echo "<font color=\"#fff\">Description: {$row[doc]['des']}</font><P><br /><P>";
                        echo "<a href=\"https://twitter.com/share\" class=\"twitter-share-button\" data-lang=\"en\">Tweet</a><br><br>";
                        print '<div id="like-button"></div>';
                        echo "<td valign=\"top\">";
                        echo "<div class=\"playlist\" id=\"playlist\">";
                        echo "<ol>";
                        $songCount = 0;
                        foreach ($row['doc']['tracks'] as $song) {
                            ++$songCount;

                            $songUrl = $row['doc']['baseurl'] . urldecode($song['url']);
                            echo "<li><a href=\"#\" data-src=\"{$songUrl}\">{$song['name']}</a><div id=\"download\"><a href=\"{$songUrl}\">Download</a></li>";
                        }
                        echo "</ol>";
                        echo "<br><div id=\"player\"><audio preload></audio></div>";
                        echo "</div>";
                        echo "<P>";
                        echo "<small>To download a single MP3 at a time:</br><b>Windows OS:</b> hold the ALT button on the keyboard and click the Download button<br><b>Mac OSX:</b> hold the OPTION button on the keyboard and click the Download button<P><BR><b>Controls:</b><br>Play/Pause = spacebar</br>Next track = Right arrow<br>Previous track = Left arrow";
                        echo '</tr></td></table>';
    }



            }



    exit;
?>
<!----NOTTING SHOWING UP---->
  <!-- begin htmlcommentbox.com -->
 <div id="HCB_comment_box"><a href="http://www.htmlcommentbox.com">HTML Comment Box</a> is loading comments...</div>
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" id="hcb"> /*<!--*/ if(!window.hcb_user){hcb_user={};} (function(){s=document.createElement("script");s.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");s.setAttribute("src", "http://www.htmlcommentbox.com/jread?page="+escape((window.hcb_user && hcb_user.PAGE)||(""+window.location)).replace("+","%2B")+"&opts=0&num=10");if (typeof s!="undefined") document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);})(); /*-->*/ </script>
<!-- end htmlcommentbox.com -->
```

Comment: remove the `exit;` at the end, it will appear

Comment: OT: I recommend to have a look at examples where PHP is embedded in HTML rather than HTML being `echo`ed by PHP. It makes your (echoed) HTML incredibly hard to maintain.

Comment: As a side note, jsFiddle is for testing JavaScript, it wouldn't help in this case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you are using `exit`, which terminates the script.  Get rid of that and it will continue to output the HTML underneath.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php

Answer (score 1):

Omit the exit.

Exit will end Php processing.

Answer (score 1):

With php exit the parser stops, and hands back all the content gathered until that point to the web server. Simply delete the exit; row.